# Windows fast startup in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, 20.04

Can someone please put up a list of all the impacts that Windows "FAST STARTUP" has on Ubuntu during dual boot. (Some impacts seem to be debatable...)

Comment: Please list the impacts you see. I only know one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: You can't mount your Windows drives read-write in Ubuntu, when Windows fast boot is enabled, since Windows wont flush latest updates to disk when shutting down but keep them in a state-file, so the filesystem will not be in a consistent state.

Comment: Does this include drives that are not the windows system partition? Anyway, I could mount and even write to partitions with the fast startup on. The changes were there when I booted with windows. This is the reason that I made this thread. Also, I want to know whether the grub menu will appear with fast startup.

Comment: This include all drives in Windows, C:\, D:\ ... and so on. Windows should show up in Grub irrespective of fast boot setting .. but please try it out your self.

Comment: The grub does appear. I suppose it appears even when you hibernate because it does for me. Anyway, I can mount and write in NTFS partitions. Even the C:\ How is this possible?